# Excel workbook to open automatically every time I turn on my PC

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel

Is there any way that every time I turn on my PC, an excel workbook of my selection to open automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method to do this is by doing the following:

In explorer, go to the location of your excel file that you want to start at startup.

Right-click the excel sheet and press `copy`.

Now, click in the addressbar in an empty space, such that you can type in it.

Type in the following: `shell:startup`

Your explorer window will now change to the location where startup files can be placed.

In an empty section in this window, right-click and choose `Paste as shortcut`.

A shortcut to the excel document will be placed in your startup, and from now on, every time you start your computer up, this file will be launched.

Keep in mind, if you put your computer into sleep or hibernation, this will not start. If you do start->shutdown, it will run on next launch.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, first create a batch file with the content:

```
@"Excel.exe full path" "Workbook full path"
```

Then go to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp and copy the batch file there.